# Why does beamer's \insertauthor report as nonempty?

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I'm working on a beamer theme in which each of the title page elements is optional; for example, I don't want defining an empty date to produce a large empty space on the title slide.
I figured I could do this by wrapping the layout for each element in a conditional like so:

```
\ifx\insertdate\empty%
\else
   ...
   \insertdate
   \vskip{1em}
   ...
\fi
```

And this pattern works as expected... except for the author. For whatever reason, `\ifx\insertauthor\empty` never seems to evaluate to `true`, unlike the other title page elements:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
  \ifx\insertauthor\empty
    empty
  \else
    nonempty
  \fi
  % outputs "nonempty"

  \ifx\insertdate\empty
    empty
  \else
    nonempty
  \fi
  % outputs "empty"
\end{document}
```

Why is this? Is there any workaround that would let me test for an empty author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition text of `\insertauthor` is not empty, which is quite obvious, because the macro is meant to do something with data that should already have been given.

From `beamerbasetitle.sty`, line 149 and following:

```
% The \author command
%
%
\def\author{\@dblarg\beamer@author}
\long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}#2}%
  \def\beamer@shortauthor{#1}%
  \ifbeamer@autopdfinfo%
    \def\beamer@andstripped{}%
    \beamer@stripands#2 \and\relax
    {\let\inst=\@gobble\let\thanks=\@gobble\def\and{, }\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\beamer@andstripped}}}
  \fi%
}
```

So when you specify `\author` (with or without the optional argument), `\insertauthor` is defined (and not empty). Since on line 173 we find

```
\author{}
```

we deduce that `\insertauthor` is initialized and is never empty at the start of a `beamer` job.

You're probably better served by testing `\beamer@shortauthor`, which will be indeed empty at the start of a job, until another `\author` command appears.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ifx\beamer@shortauthor\empty
  empty
\else
  nonempty
\fi
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take some inspiration from beamer, e.g. from https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/1b04c51a596a51530adeff278ca2c43aa963c9b1/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemeinmargin.sty#L68-L74 and replicate this test. This has the advantage that the author names will be printed on the title page even if your users choose an empty short author:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author[]{test}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@andstripped}{
  empty
}{%
  nonempty
}
\makeatother

  \ifx\insertdate\empty
    empty
  \else
    nonempty
  \fi
  % outputs "empty"
\end{document}
```

(there was an issue for users of the `usepdftitle=false` class option, this is already fixed in the beamer dev version and should be included in beamer v3.72 or newer)